# Could we use ground effect (over water) to increase an airliner's range?

Tags: aircraft-performance, airliner, ground-effect

Theoretically, would it be possible to increase the range of a modern jetliner in ground effect over the sea?

Comment: It's important to consider that a jet engine is more fuel efficient at higher altitude.  An aircraft designed to fly in ground effect probably wouldn't be designed to fly at modern airliner speed though.  Commenting instead of answering because I'm not going to put a lot of rigor in.

Comment: Short answer is no, but the Soviets did build a craft designed to use ground effect.  Ekranoplan:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lun-class_ekranoplan

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. I appreciate it. I asked the original question not to find out if there is any practical application because I suspect there is not. However, in the case of MH370, its worth exploring all avenues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but.

Flying in ground effect clearly reduces the power required to stay airborne. Accidents like the one [in this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87896/can-airspeed-in-ground-effect-be-used-to-estimate-climb-performance) are only possible because airplanes can take off at altitudes above their ceiling, but then fail to climb.

This means flying as slowly as practical. Then the gains from ground effect  will be greatest.

But a modern airliner is built to fly fast. Now let's see what needs to be changed in order to adapt it to the new regime:

- No wing sweep
- Thicker airfoils. Mach is no longer restricting optimum airfoil thickness.
- Less aspect ratio.
- Propellers instead of jets.
- Much less installed power, so engines are not heavier than needed and run at optimum efficiency.
- A comparatively larger horizontal tail

In other words: This will be a radically different airplane, and it will need much longer runways or even catapults to take off with its low installed power. Next, transatlantic flights will take three times longer at least, more than a full day, almost like in the days when Atlantic crossings were flown exclusively by airship. But it will need less energy, so once energy prices dominate fares, an Atlantic crossing by ground effect will cost less than by conventional airliner. However, since one flight takes so much longer, a much larger fleet of airliners is needed to transport the same number of people, so capital cost need to be taken into consideration, too.

For an inspiration how this airplane could look like, the past offers a good example: The Dornier Do-X. I once read (sorry, no source) that passengers on a steamer heard its typical engine sound and began to scan the sky for this airplane, only to discover it flying below their own height in ground effect, almost skimming the waves.

[image: Do-X after liftoff]

Do-X after liftoff (picture [source](https://www.recreationalflying.com/uploads/monthly_2021_01/997610186_DornierDo-Xliftoff.thumb.jpg.8f4d8405306f125ed72c0f235c729ed9.jpg))

If you now ask the passengers which mode of travel they prefer, only the very cheap ones will pick the ground effect airliner. The ones which contribute the major share of airline profits will prefer the faster route through the stratopause.

Comment: That plane is flying lower than most large bulk cargo ships sailing these days...